# Scala resolve multiple Futures and get a Map(String, AnyRef)

Tags: scala

I am currently trying to resolve multiple futures at once but as some of them may fail, I don't want to get a failure on all if one of them fails, instead, end up with a `Map(String, AnyRef)` (meaning a Map with the future name and the response converted to what a need).

Currently I have the following:

```
val fsResp = channelList.map {
  channelRef => channelRef.ask(ReportStatus).mapTo[EventMessage]
}

Future.sequence(fsResp).onComplete{
  case Success(resp: Seq[EventMessage]) =>
    resp.foreach { event => Supervisor.foreach(_ ! event) }

    val channels = loadConfiguredComponents()
      .collect {
        case ("processor" | "external", components) => components.map {
          case (name, config: Channel) =>
            (name, serializeDetails(config, resp.find(_.channel == ChannelName(name))))
        }
      }.flatten.toMap

    val event = EventMessage(...)

    Supervisor.foreach(_ ! event)

  case Failure(exception) => originalSender ! replayError(exception.getMessage)

}
```

But this fails if any of those fails. So How can I end up with a `Map(channelRef.path.name, event() | exception)` ?

Thanks!

Comment: `onComplete` is not for `Future` composition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fallbackTo in order to avoid a Failure. In this example I change Future[T] to Future[Option[T]] in order to fallback to None, and then remove None elements.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def method(value:Int) = { Thread.sleep(2000); println(value); value  }

println("start")

val eventualNone = Future.successful(None)

val futures = List(Future(method(1)), Future(method(2)), Future(method(3)), Future(throw new RuntimeException))

val withoutFailures = futures.map(_.map(Option.apply).fallbackTo(eventualNone))

Future.sequence(withoutFailures).map(_.flatten).onComplete {
  case Success(values) => println(values)
  case Failure(ex:Throwable) => println("FAIL")
}

Thread.sleep(5000)
```

output

```
start
1
3
2
List(1, 2, 3)
```

Can be changed to Either[Throwable, T] instead of Option[T] if you want to know what fails.

This code always be Success (regarding the Future result), so you need to inspect your values in order to know if all futures fail.

Comment: Awsome! Gracias Sebastian!

Answer (score 0):

To capture successful/failed values from the list of Futures, you can first apply `map/recover` to each of them, then use `Future.sequence` to transform the result list into a Future of `List[Either[Throwable,EventMessage]]`, as shown in the following trivialized example:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class EventMessage(id: Int, msg: String)

val fsResp = List(
  Future{EventMessage(1, "M1")}, Future{throw new Throwable()}, Future{EventMessage(3, "M3")}
)

val f = Future.sequence(
  fsResp.map( _.map{ resp =>
    // Do stuff with `resp`, add item to `Map()`, etc ...
    Right(resp)
  }.
  recover{ case e: Throwable =>
    // Log `exception` info, etc ...
    Left(e)
  } )
)

Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
// f: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Product with Serializable with scala.util.
//   Either[Throwable,EventMessage]]] = Future(Success(List(
//     Right(EventMessage(1,M1)), Left(java.lang.Throwable), Right(EventMessage(3,M3))
//   )))
```

Comment: This throws me an error `Expression of type Left(Throwable, Nothing) doesn't conform expected type Right(Nothing, EventMessage)`. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: @Fede E., I'm not able to reproduce the said error using the sample code.  If `fsResp` conforms to being a list of `Future[EventMessage]`, and `Right(resp)` and `Left(e)` are returned as shown in the sample code, the result Future should consist of a list of `Either[Throwable, EventMessage]`.